# PHP PDO Session redirecting me to login page

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I am trying to improve my skills in PHP. I came from PHP procedural and shifting to PHP using PDO which will make my web application more secured to prevent SQL Injections or XSS attacks. I created a login form that is working fine that the user can input either email or username and followed by a password to verify that is encrypted in the back-end. I used password_hash() for my encryption in the registration form.

So here is the code in my login PHP to authenticate the user below

```
<?php  
 session_start();  
 $host = "localhost";  
 $username = "root";  
 $password = "";  
 $database = "test";  
 $message = "";  
 try  
 {  
      $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
      $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
      if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
      {  
           if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))  
           {  
                $message = '
                <script>
                sweetAlert("Incorrect username or password!", "Please try again.", "error");
                </script>;
                ';  
           }  
           else  
           {
                // User login authentication  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_type = :user_type AND (username = :username OR email = :username) LIMIT 1";  
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);  
                $statement->execute(  
                     array(  
                          'username'     =>     $_POST["username"],
                          'email'        =>     $_POST["username"],
                          'user_type'    => 'user'
                          // 'archive'      =>     1
                     )  
                );  
                $count = $statement->rowCount();

                // Administrator login authentication
                $query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_type = :user_type AND (username = :username OR email = :username) LIMIT 1";  
                $statement2 = $connect->prepare($query2);  
                $statement2->execute(  
                     array(  
                          'username'     =>     $_POST["username"],
                          'email'        =>     $_POST["username"],
                          'user_type'    => 'admin'
                          // 'archive'      =>     1
                     )  
                );
                $count2 = $statement2->rowCount();

                if($count > 0)  
                {  
                     $result = $statement->fetch();

                    //check password
                    if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $result['password'])) {
                        $_SESSION["login_user"] = $_POST["username"];
                        exit(header("location:user/dashboard.php"));
                    } else {
                         $message = '
                          <script>
                          sweetAlert("Incorrect username or password!", "Please try again.", "error");
                          </script>;
                          '; 
                    } 
                }
                else if($count2 > 0)  
                {  
                     $result2 = $statement2->fetch();

                    //check password
                    if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $result2['password'])) {
                        $_SESSION["login_admin"] = $_POST["username"];
                        exit(header("location:admin/dashboard.php"));
                    } else {
                         $message = '
                          <script>
                          sweetAlert("Incorrect username or password!", "Please try again.", "error");
                          </script>;
                          '; 
                    }   
                }

                else  
                {  
                      $message = '
                      <script>
                      sweetAlert("Incorrect username or password!", "Please try again.", "error");
                      </script>;
                      ';  
                }  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 catch(PDOException $error)  
 {  
      $message = $error->getMessage();  
 }  
 ?>
```

But everything here works fine and vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. So it is redirecting to the right place if the user has inputted the correct data.

But when I added the session it redirects me back to the login page.

Here is the code in my **session.php** below

```
<?php
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbname     = "test";
    $dbuser     = "root";
    $dbpass     = "";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    session_start();
    $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :user_check OR username = :user_check");
    $result->execute(array(":usercheck"=>$user_check));

    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $login_session = $row['username'];
    $ln_session = $row['last_name'];
    $fn_session = $row['first_name'];
    $user_id =$row['id'];
    // $user_passwords = $row['password'];

    if(!isset($login_session))
        {
            $conn = null; 
            header('Location: ../index.php');
        }
?>
```

I would include in the admin its just because the same procedure but different session to be checked. So I think I messed up with the session?

Appreciate if someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's good that you're trying to level up your skills, but keep in mind PDO can only protect you from SQL injection attacks *if* and only if you use prepared statements with placeholder values or are extremely vigilant about escaping things when you can't do that. It does **nothing** to protect you from XSS or CSRF attacks, those are separate concerns unrelated to databases.

Comment: Remember, writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong, so unless this is *purely for academic reasons*, please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. You may think you've done it right, but if you go live you may find out the hard way you missed something.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! @tadman I already start learning Laravel and studied the MVC architecture and concepts of OOP. However I want to master the basic and fundamentals of PHP from Procedural, OOP and PDO that I am doing right now. Thankyou btw! I'll take note of this.

Comment: Don't forget you can learn the fundamentals from within the context of a framework, you can always dig deeper into the code and see how it's implemented or write your own lower level code. Laravel is still PHP at the end of the day, and to use it effectively you'll need to know the PHP core API.

Comment: I'm digging in to that, especially in working with REST API. Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you used ':user_check' as a parameter in the SQL string but, you used ':usercheck' as an index in the array on execute() function. You need to use the same parameter name on the sql string and in indexes of array in execute function.

Comment: wait I'll try that later when I get back home and I'll update you with it. Didn't see that coming.

Comment: It worked. I just got lazy looking at my code I guest lol. Btw Thanks for the help!